# C : Array of pointers giving segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am learning the concept of array of pointers and i was wondering why this piece of code is giving me a segmentation fault,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, *ptr[3] = { 0 };

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("Value of var[%d] = %d\n", i, *ptr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Please help!!!

Comment: you're trying to access address `0`

Answer (score 1):

`ptr[i]` represents the contents of the element occupying the position number `i` in the array taking into account that the first one is the `0`. Your array has been declared to have space to hold three pointers to integers. Initializing the array with `{0}` you are telling the computer to store `0` in the first one pointer, the one occupying the first position (position `0`). By default, the rest of elements of your array are automatically initialized with `0`. Thus, all three pointers points to the `0` position which is an illegal one. So that, when you try to show the contents of the memory indicated by each pointer `(*ptr[i])` you get the segmentation fault error.

best regards

Comment: Then what is the exact difference between 1D array and array of pointers?

Comment: What makes you think there's a difference? An array is an array, whether it's an array of `int`, or an array of pointers.